# Trying to create a fragment with a spinner in it

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I'm trying to have a spinner inside my fragment. The constructor for an ArrayAdapter has a reference to a context.  On my activity, I would put this as the parameter i.e

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

When I copied this code into my fragment class it underlined it with red for having the wrong parameters.
How can I get this to work?

The Code:-

```
 void setUpSpinner()
    {

        Spinner spinner2;
        spinner2 = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getContext()` instead of `this`

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Because in `Fragment` `this` isn't a `Context`, `Fragment` class doesn't inherited from `Context`. So use `Context` of the parent `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You Are Writing `this` In The ArrayAdapter Which Is A Fragment But It Requires A Context

**`Your Code`**:-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this/*Over Here*/,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

**`Correct Code`**:-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below for creating adapter and see if it works.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activityContext,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Use this for reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner